# Send nested objects to oracle stored procedure through mybatis

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

How to call a oracle stored procedure with nested list as parameter?
Ex: `CALL procedure(arg1)` where `arg1` is `list [1,2,[1,2,3]]`. I have written a typehandler to map the arguments but how to map `[1,2,3]`

Ex: Pseudocode

```
STRUCT struct = new STRUCT(structDescriptor, connection, new Object[]{1,2,?});
ArrayDescriptor = new ArrayDescriptor(arrayDescriptor ,connection, struct);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by sending array of structs